# Vulkan-Device Properties is NULL

Tags: c++, graphics, vulkan

I am currently learning Vulkan 1.3, I am following the Tutorial from https://vulkan-tutorial.com, My Device Properties struct is null, including my Vulkan Physical Device. IDK What to do.

```
Main.cpp
```

```
#include "Engine.h"

int main()
{
    Engine* renderer = new Engine();
    
    renderer->RenderScreen();

    return 0;
}
```

```
Engine.h
```

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>

//Validation Layer Extensions Names
const static std::vector<const char*> VLNames =
{
    "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation"
};

class Engine
{
public:

    Engine() = default;

    void RenderScreen();
    
    ~Engine();
    

private:

    GLFWwindow* _Window;
    VkInstance _Instance;
    VkPhysicalDevice _Device; //Suitable Graphics Card

    bool InitializeWindow();
    bool InitializeVulkan();
    void ChooseGraphicsCard();
    void CheckForQueue();
    
};
```

```
Engine.cpp
```

```
#include "Engine.h"

void Engine::RenderScreen()
{
    Engine::InitializeWindow();
    Engine::InitializeVulkan();
    Engine::ChooseGraphicsCard();
    Engine::CheckForQueue();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(_Window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

}

Engine::~Engine()
{   
    vkDestroyInstance(_Instance, nullptr);
    glfwDestroyWindow(_Window);
    glfwTerminate();
}

bool Engine::InitializeWindow()
{

    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

    _Window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 480, "Renderer", nullptr, nullptr);

    if (_Window == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Window Creation Failed" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }


    return true;
}

bool Engine::InitializeVulkan()
{
    //Extracting Vulkan Version and Selecting a Suitable Version
    uint32_t VulkanVersion = 0;

    vkEnumerateInstanceVersion(&VulkanVersion);

    std::cout << "Vulkan Version " <<
        "Major: " << VK_API_VERSION_MAJOR(VulkanVersion) << std::endl <<
        "Minor: " << VK_API_VERSION_MINOR(VulkanVersion) << std::endl <<
        "Patch: " << VK_API_VERSION_PATCH(VulkanVersion) << std::endl;

    uint32_t VulkanVersionToUse = VK_MAKE_API_VERSION(0, 1, 2, 0);


    //Application Create Info
    VkApplicationInfo AppInfo = {};
    AppInfo.apiVersion = VulkanVersionToUse;
    AppInfo.applicationVersion = VulkanVersionToUse;
    AppInfo.engineVersion = VulkanVersionToUse;
    AppInfo.pApplicationName = "Triangle Renderer";
    AppInfo.pEngineName = "Engine";
    AppInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    AppInfo.pNext = nullptr;


    //Getting Required Extensions for Vulkan to Render on GLFW Window
    uint32_t RequiredGLFWExtensionCount = 0;
    const char** pRequiredGLFWExtensionName = nullptr;
    pRequiredGLFWExtensionName = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&RequiredGLFWExtensionCount);

    //Getting Supported Extenions by Vulkan For the Specific Computer

    uint32_t SupportedVulkanExtensionCount = 0;

    //This Gets The Number of Supported Extensions By That Instance
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &SupportedVulkanExtensionCount, nullptr);
    
    std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> SupportedVulkanExtensions(SupportedVulkanExtensionCount);

    //This Gets The Details of Supported Extensions by That Instance
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &SupportedVulkanExtensionCount, SupportedVulkanExtensions.data());

    /*
    //Printing the Data in Debug Log
    std::cout << "Supported Vulkan Extensions for This Instance: ";
    for (const auto& Extension : SupportedVulkanExtensions)
    {
        std::cout << Extension.extensionName << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Required GLFW Extensions for Rendering Vulkan: " << *(pRequiredGLFWExtensionName) << std::endl;
    */

    //Instance Create Info
    VkInstanceCreateInfo InstanceInfo = {};
    InstanceInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    InstanceInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    InstanceInfo.pApplicationInfo = &AppInfo;
    InstanceInfo.enabledExtensionCount = RequiredGLFWExtensionCount;
    InstanceInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = pRequiredGLFWExtensionName;
    InstanceInfo.flags = 0;
    InstanceInfo.enabledLayerCount = (uint32_t)VLNames.size();
    InstanceInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = VLNames.data();
    
    VkResult Result = {};

    //Creating the Instance
    Result = vkCreateInstance(&InstanceInfo, nullptr, &_Instance);

    //Error Check
    if (Result != VK_SUCCESS)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to Create Instance");
        return false;
    }

    //Choosing Graphics Card

    Engine::ChooseGraphicsCard();

    return true;
}

void Engine::ChooseGraphicsCard()
{
    /*Collecting Information About Graphics Card*/

    uint32_t GraphicsCardCount = 0;

    //Fetches the Number of Available Graphics Card with Vulkan Support
    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(_Instance, &GraphicsCardCount, nullptr);

    if (GraphicsCardCount == 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("No Suitable Graphics Card Found to Render Vulkan");
    }

    std::vector<VkPhysicalDevice> GraphicsCards(GraphicsCardCount);

    //Fetches The Details of Available Graphics Card
    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(_Instance, &GraphicsCardCount, GraphicsCards.data());

    std::cout << "Number of Supported Graphics Card Available: " << GraphicsCards.size() << std::endl;
    
    //For Our Purpose, Selects First Enumerated Graphics Card as Preferrred Graphics Card
    for (const auto& GraphicsCard : GraphicsCards)
    {
        _Device = GraphicsCard;
        break;
    }

    //Checks for Presence of Graphics Card
    if (_Device = NULL)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("ERROR: No Suitable Graphics Card Found!");
    }

    //There is SOME BUG HERE!!!!!!!!\\
    //Fetches Properties of Graphics Card
    VkPhysicalDeviceProperties DeviceProperties = {};
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties(_Device, &DeviceProperties);
    
    std::cout << "Graphics Card in Use: " << DeviceProperties.deviceName << std::endl;
}

void Engine::CheckForQueue()
{


}
```

I Tried Checking the locals in Visual Studio, but I am getting  `_Device` as NULL. I am Clueless about what wrong I could have committed.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF0QC.png)

After Displaying This much, Visual Studio Debugger Stops and Throws a Error Like

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE3E580180 (vulkan-1.dll) in OpenGL_Renderer1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

Comment: I Do have a Valid Graphics Card That can Run the Vulkan, Because The Default Cube App Runs Perfectly

Comment: Have you tried the Vulkan validation layer, and does it show any problems?

Comment: Currently, My Console Tells that Vulkan Validation Layer Active, But it doesn't throw any Error

Comment: Can you post the output from your program (device counts and listings etc), maybe the problem is in the _Device selection.

Comment: You need to be checking return codes for runtime errors. Also you call `ChooseGraphicsCard()` twice.

Comment: `if (_Device = NULL)` probably isn't right. There's also a lot of other strange things throughout the code, like choosing the device twice, or using `new` for the Engine class without a clear need or a `delete`, or invoking class member functions in an unnecessarily verbose and confusing way.